# Testing whether two polynomial in $\Bbb{C}[x,y,z,a,b,c]$ are equal given relations between $x,y,z,a,b,c$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, reference-request, algorithms

Say I am given $f,g\in R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,a,b,c]$, of known degrees. Say I am also given $t_1,...,t_n\in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z,a,b,c]$. I would like to show that $f\equiv g \pmod{I}$ where $I=Rt_1+...+Rt_n$ the ideal generated by $t_1,...,t_n$.

I am interested in a non-probabilistic algorithm for solving this problem.

While researching I came across the Schwartz–Zippel lemma, however, this gives rise to a probabilistic algorithm while I want to know for certain whether $f\equiv g \pmod{I}$.

Is there an algorithm, perhaps not optimal, that answers this type of question?

If $I=0$ we could just choose enough points in $\mathbb{C}^6$ and see that $f$ and $g$ agree on them, hence they have the same coefficients and so are equal.

I know that in general, this problem (with $I=0$) is NP-complete but I still would like an algorithm, even a bad one, for solving such problems.

The problem is $I\neq 0$ so a more subtle approach is needed.

Comment: Could you compute a Groebner basis for $I$, then just check if $f-g$ is in $I$ using it?